# PDO IP Set is duplicating behind Reverse Proxy

Tags: php

So i have my IP Update button on my site set so it gets their ip instead of them inputting it. In PDO, this is what i got:

```
public function updateIP($id){
        return $this->update("users",array("ip"=>$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']),"id",$id);
    }
```

How can i make this so that the IP dosent return with multiple IPs?

Heres a picture of the results:
[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inBuY.png)

Many thanks

Comment: edit: has to be HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR due to my site having a reverse proxy

Comment: retagged as I see no PDO in the question

Comment: that's an http header and comes from the user and/or your own proxies. if you don't want multiple IPs, then you'll have to pre-process that header to remove the extras, or configure your proxy to remove them there.